# What is the format to upload content to confluence by REST?

Tags: rest, wiki, confluence

I found some information about the REST interface of Confluence (https://docs.atlassian.com/atlassian-confluence/REST/6.6.0/#content-update), but I have not understood yet which format is expected for the content of the page that should be created or updated.

Is it HTML? Or the Confluence Wiki markup? Or something else?

Note that I am not interested in Confluence Cloud, only on premise.

Comment: To the close voter: I am not looking for tool recommendations. Anyway, the question is already solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `rest/api/content/` accepts

```json
{
    "type": "page",
    "title": "`some title",
    "space": {
        "key": "ICXMV"
    },
    "body": {
         "wiki": {
            "value": "h1. Hello world!",
            "representation": "wiki"
        }
    }
}
```

So it is possible to upload content in the Confluence Wiki format.

Comment: That is JavaScript Object Notation (JSON), FYI.
https://www.json.org/json-en.html

Comment: Sorry, my answer was not clear so I edited it.